# XGBoost Classifier: eval_metric unexpected pred. shape

Tags: python, classification, xgboost

I have a problem with my XGBoost Classifier. I tried to use a custom function to evaluate my model later on. I can use this function for an eval_metric if I am using the XGB Regressor but not with the Classifier.
I have 3 labels, just let them name y1, y2, y3, and the prediction of the fit function for my eval_metric function is of shape (n, 3) with n = len(testdata). Therefore I do not have a prediction, but I have 3 values for the test prediction. If I am using the Regressor, everything is fine, and during the fit, my eval_metric gets predictions of shape (n, 1) (One for each label).
I hope you understand my problem. I have an illustration as source code:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
class = XGBClassifier()
X_train = "train data with shape (m, 144)"
y_train = "train labels with shape (m, 1)"
X_test = "test data with shape (120000, 144)"
y_test = "test labels with shape (120000, 1)"

def eval_function(predicted, true):
    print(shape(predicted)) #This will be shape (120000, 3) an not as expected (120000, 1)
    print(shape(predicted)) #This will be shape (120000, 1) as expected
    return 1

class.fit(X_train, y_train, evals_set=[(X_test, y_test)], eval_metric=eval_function)
```

Now the problem is that the fit function gives my "eval_function" an array of shape (120000, 3) and not (120000, 1) as the Regressor does and how I would have expected it. Maybe cause I have 3 different labels? What do I have to do to get the actually predicted label to make a custom evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of XGBoost, the prediction object follows these rules :

> ... for multi-class classification problem, XGBoost builds one tree for each class and the trees for each class are called a “group” of trees, so output dimension may change due to used model. After 1.4 release, we added a new parameter called strict_shape, one can set it to True to indicate a more restricted output is desired...

> ...for multi-class with multi:softprob the number of columns equals to number of classes...

Complete documentation here :
[XGBoost Prediction Documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prediction.html)

Basically XBoost uses one vs all methode, "is it that class or anothoer one?" for each class, and keeps the class with the best "probability" (yeah it's a shortcut term).

That's it for the dimension issue part.

But as a remark, it does not make sense to use the same metrics to evaluate a Regressor and a Classifier.